# how to resove "connection.blocked: true" in capabilities on the RabbitMQ UI

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, airflow

"rabbitmqctl list_connections" shows as running but on the UI in the connections tab, under client properties, i see "connection.blocked:   true".

I can see that messages are in queued in RabbitMq and the connection is in idle state.

I am running Airflow with Celery. My jobs are not executing at all.

Is this the reason why jobs are not executing?

How to resolve the issue so that my jobs start running

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same kind of issue by just using celery.

It seems that when you have a lot of messages in the queue, and these are fairly chunky, and your node memory goes high, the rabbitMQ memory watermark gets trespassed and this triggers a blocking into consumer connections, so  no worker can access that node (and related queues).

At the same time publishers are happily sending stuff via the exchange so you get in a lose-lose situation.

The only solution we had is to avoid hitting that memory watermark and scale up the  number of consumers.
Keep messages/tasks lean so that the signature is not MB but KB